# Is this construction correct? "Something is not .... However, it is, if..."

Tags: sentence-construction

Let me explain the construction i'd like to use by an example:

A number is not generally divided by 10. However, it is, if its last digit is 0.

To me, it seems logically correct, but I'm not entirely sure. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence seems right apart from the fact that I would change *divided* to *divisible*:

> A number is not generally **divisible** by 10. However, it is, if its last digit is 0.

Divisible suits the definition more as [it means](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/divisible):

> **capable of being evenly divided, without remainder**

Therefore, *divisible* is more suitable.

**You can also use *evenly divisible* to emphasise even more that there is no remainder**.

Comment: "Evenly divisible" would emphasize even more that you mean with no remainder.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty thanks - added to my post

Comment: Thank you! Can you think of any alternative form for this kind of sentence?

Comment: @giulio Something like: *Generally, a number is evenly divisible by 10 only if it ends in 0*...